# Get number of filtered items with a backward reference to a model Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I have being playing with this for hours with out find a solution.

I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Then I filter the Items and the categories related to that item:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(name=name)
categories = Category.filter(id__in = items.values_list('category__id'))
```

Now I want to get the number of the items with a category and save that number in a field in categories with `annotate`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
from django.db.models import Count

items = Item.objects.filter(name=name)
categories = Category.objects.filter(
    id__in=items.values_list('category_id')
).annotate(items_count=Count("item"))

for cat in categories:
    print cat.name, cat.items_count
```

for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. `Count("item")` will count all the items associated to each category included those that didn't pass the filter.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I filter the Items and the categories related to that item.

If each item can point to several categories, I think you need ManyToMany field.

> Now I want to get the number of the items with a category

```
category = Category.objects.filter(name=name)
num_items = Item.objects.filter(category=category).count()
```

Comment: Each category have multiple items but an item have only one category. I could get the number of items with a category one by one but it will make as many queries as categories you have.